# HTML link error to PHP pages

Tags: php, html

I have a few buttons that are properly linked on my website, it rarely works, most of the time it does not. when I right click and open in a new window they work else it wont.

```
 http://studentnet.kingston.ac.uk/k1003140/group8
```

Any one knows why and how?

here how they are linked:

```
<a href="spain.php">Spain</a>
```

and the page spain exists. please do not give me a minus if you won't even comment.

Comment: provide a link of your website please

Comment: @Ahmedskaya  `http://studentnet.kingston.ac.uk/k1003140/group8`

Comment: sorry i didn't notice, i replied you anyway =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your website and i found you have a js script called general.js it calls this function

```
$(document).ready(function()    {
    //initial
    $('#midcontent').load('content/index.php');

    //handle menu clicks
    $('ul li a').click(function() {
        var page = $ (this).attr('href');
        $('#midcontent').load('content/' + page + '.php');
        return false;
    });
});
```

and content/index.php is unreachable and causes an error in the console log, when i disabled javascript on your webpage the links worked fine.

as you see it adds extra content/ before the link and .php at the end, try to remove it